# I cannot seem to find a string in a subarray in an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to find a string in an array but even though the string is contained in the array the variable comes up with False when I print the variable I used to find the string. Any help would be appreciated, here is the code down below:

```
Name='Admin'
array=[['Joseph', '03', '01', 'NN'], ['Seph', '10', '08', '09'], ['Jo', '05', '04', '07'], ['Mark', '01', 'NN', 'NN'], ['BigDave', '00', '02', 'NN'], ['Davy', '03', 'NN', 'NN'], ['Admin', '10', 'NN', 'N']]
check=Name in array
print(check)
```

The outcome of this print results in this `False` and I don't understand why it does this.

Comment: Because `in array` only searches the top level of the list, not the inner lists. Did you mean e.g. `check = any(Name in subarray for subarray in array)` or `any(subarray[0] == Name ...)`? Alternatively, restructure your data - a dictionary `{'Joseph': ['03', '01', 'nn'], ...}` would let you look up names in `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`.

Comment: Yes I would do that but it would mean I have to restructure my data complier

Comment: @jonrshape I also need to be able to append the dictionary

Comment: What do you mean *"append the dictionary"*? You can append to *the lists inside the dictionary*, or add new keys with their own list values. I suggest you run through an introductory tutorial covering data structures.

Comment: Adding a new item to a dict is trivial. `theDict[newKey] = newValue` where `theValue` can be a list as you would probably use.

Comment: I need to write lines one at  a time into the dictionary without erasing then lists inside of the dicitonary @jonrshape

Comment: Why do you believe adding 'lines' to the dict would erase existing lines?

Comment: @jwpfox Because sometimes it erases the variable

Comment: No, it does not. It will overwrite existing keys of course.

Comment: Okay thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you ask if `'Admin'` is in array, it doesn't check nested arrays. You would have to loop through them to see if `'Admin'` exists in one of them.

```
Name='Admin'
array=[['Joseph', '03', '01', 'NN'], ['Seph', '10', '08', '09'], ['Jo', '05', '04', '07'], ['Mark', '01', 'NN', 'NN'], ['BigDave', '00', '02', 'NN'], ['Davy', '03', 'NN', 'NN'], ['Admin', '10', 'NN', 'N']]
for subArray in array:
    if Name in subArray:
        print subArray
```

Outputs:

```
['Admin', '10', 'NN', 'N']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = []
Name='Admin'
array=[['Joseph', '03', '01', 'NN'], ['Seph', '10', '08', '09'],   ['Jo','05', '04', '07'], ['Mark', '01', 'NN', 'NN'], ['BigDave', '00', '02', 'NN'], ['Davy', '03', 'NN', 'NN'], ['Admin', '10', 'NN', 'N']]
for i in xrange(len(array)):
   for j in xrange(len(array[i])):
      print i, "...........", j, ".........", ls.append(array[i][j])

if 'Joseph' in ls:
   print 'yes'
else:
   print 'no'
```

Hence there is no 'name' keyword in your code so i have put 'Joseph' keyword from your list

Comment: Too complex for what I want

Answer (score 0):

You could do something silly like this:

```
Name='Admin'
array=[['Joseph', '03', '01', 'NN'], ['Seph', '10', '08', '09'], ['Jo', '05', '04', '07'], ['Mark', '01', 'NN', 'NN'], ['BigDave', '00', '02', 'NN'], ['Davy', '03', 'NN', 'NN'], ['Admin', '10', 'NN', 'N']]
check = True in [Name in arr for arr in array]
print(check) # prints True
```

Comment: Not at all silly, but `any(list)` is far more readable than `True in list`